# How to get a fragment in FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2, fragmentstatepageradapter

```
MyFragment currentFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                   .findFragmentByTag("f"+pagerMainAdapter.getItemId(0));
currentFragment.testRun("Hello world");
```

I'm trying to Migrate from `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2` and and I don't know how to get fragment in `ViewPager2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get the current fragment from ViewPager2:**

The `ViewPager2` has `getCurrentItem()` which returns the current page number
So, we need to link each page fragment to the corresponding page number.

But we can get a `ViewPager2` fragment by its id (item id), so the first step is to have page Ids that equals to the corresponding position, to do so override `getItemId` in the `ViewPager2` `FragmentStateAdapter`.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Then to get the current fragment:

```
int pageId = viewpager.getCurrentItem();

MyFragment currentFragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                              .findFragmentByTag("f" + pageId);
```

**EDIT:**

Apart from the question, getting the `viewPager` fragment using `"f$id"` can be discontinued some day by Google in internal APIs; so you should use another way for that; here is a one that can be used in API 24+:

Using `newInstance` page fragment pattern, you can set some argument in the `viewPager` page fragment, assuming `viewPager` fragment is `PagerFragment`:

Argument constant:

```
public static final String POSITION = "POSITION";
```

Adapter:

```
class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    
    ....

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return PagerFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

}
```

PageFragment:

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        PagerFragment fragment = new PagerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

And to get a fragment of a certain `viewPager` item:

```
int id = pagerMainAdapter.getItemId(0); // id of your ViewPager that you need to get the corresponding PageFragment

    Optional<Fragment> optionalFragment =
            getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().stream()
                    .filter(it -> it instanceof PagerFragment && it.getArguments() != null && it.getArguments().getInt(POSITION) == id)
                    .findFirst();

optionalFragment.ifPresent(fragment -> {
    // This is your needed PageFragment
});
```

Comment: This currently works, but is a kludge at best. It only works because ViewPager2 **internally** sets the fragment tags to `"f" + itemId` when they are added to the fragment manager. So if Google decides to change how that works in a future release, it will break your code. Also, would have been nice if that detail was included in the OP and/or answer.

Comment: @zen_of_kermit absolutely agreed; just a little hint; it's a part of the [`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java#351) implementation.. Let me check if this could be enhanced reliably

Comment: Don't need a hint, I looked it up and that's why I wrote **internally**. Definitely not obvious why you both have the "f" prefix without looking at the open source code.

Comment: How difficult is it for Google to add a simple getFragmentByPosition method. internally there is this mFragmentmap. I mean Android SDK is so utterly stupidly build. simple things arent possible or require some kind of hacky reflection